# Selenium C# Wait for table rows to change

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, wait

Im doing a selenium script in c# i have a table with records in it and a search box which changes the number of records shown in the table.

i.e. table shows 3 records after the search the table shows 1 records

im trying to add a wait in after the search so that it waits for the table to change to 1 so I can check that 1 record is shown.

i have tried

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.TagName("tr")));

but its not working

Any ideas

full script

```
        //login
        LoginInternal();

        //wait for company search
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("search-control-input")));

        //Enter Company
        CompanySearchBox.SendKeys(CompanyName());

        //wait for grid search 
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("search")));

        //Enter Estimate Number in Search box 
        GridSearch.Click();
        GridSearch.SendKeys("10062");

        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.TagName("tr")));

        //check how many rows after search
        var NoOfRowsAfter = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")).Count;

        Assert.AreEqual(1, NoOfRowsAfter);
        Assert.Pass();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the example of custom ExpectedCondition which waits for specified elements amount:

```
public void WaitForElementsCountToBe(By locator, int expectedCount, int secondsToWait = 10)
{
   new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToWait)).Until(d => 
   {
     return d.FindElements(locator).Count == expectedCount;
   });
}


WaitForElementsCountToBe(By.TagName("tr"), 1)
```

Comment: this hasnt worked it times out and shows  Stack Trace: 
DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)
DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition, CancellationToken token)
DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)